# Speed up audio playback by 3x faster - Swift

Tags: swift, macos, audio, avaudioplayer, playback

With AVAudioPlayer and it's 'rate' we can speed up the audio playback upto maximum 2x only. Is there any way in macOS application development with swift to speed up the playback to 3x or 4x?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1386591-setrate

is compliant with `macOS 10.8+`. did you try ?